# How do I auto-update button text in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started working with Tkinter today and can't seem to figure out how to auto-update the text of a button (like binding).

The buttons are dynamically created:

```
    #creates frames visualization
    for frame_num in range(OSBehavior.NUM_FRAMES):
        f_label = Label(frames_frame, text='Frame ' + str(frame_num))
        f_label.grid(row=frame_num, column=0, padx=5)
        f_button = Button(frames_frame, width=30, textvariable=msim.frames[frame_num].page.name)
        f_button.grid(row=frame_num, column=1, padx=5, pady=3)
```

When msim.frames[frame_num].page.name (type is string) changes, I'd like the button text to reflect that.  It indeed changes as I have a text-based version running at the same time.  However, the button text doesn't change.

If possible, I'm avoiding setting the text of the buttons manually in the backend code.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msim.frames[frame_num].page.name` needs to be an instance of a `StringVar`, it won't work with ordinary variables.